# How to know if I can have NOL (U.S. tax)?

Tags: united-states, taxes

[investopedia](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/netoperatingloss.asp&ei=_hNUU4OkENDKsQS0poD4BQ&usg=AFQjCNHPdG4dzz34pw9UGM2-ueaiKhuE-g&sig2=SR7aEfqwuKi9CBVxWrWRXQ&bvm=bv.65058239,d.cWc) defines NOL to be for a company or business. So I think an individual doesn't have NOL. Is it correct?

What is the difference between NOL and capital loss?

What are their relations then? In what cases, capital loss can be NOL?

How can I figure out if I have NOL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Individuals most definitely can have NOL. This is covered in the [IRS publication 536](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p536/ar02.html).

> What is the difference between NOL and capital loss?

NOL is **N**et **O**perating **L**oss. I.e.: a situation where your (allowable) expenses and deductions exceed your gross income. Basically it means that you have negative income for that year, for tax purposes.

Capital loss occurs when the total amount of your capital gains reported on Schedule D is negative.

> What are their relations then?

Not all expenses and deductions that you usually put on your tax return are allowed for NOL calculation. For example, capital loss is **not** allowed. I.e.: if you earned $2000 and you lost in stocks $3000 - you do **not** get a $1K NOL. Capital losses are excluded from NOL calculation and in this scenario you still have non-negative income for NOL purposes even though it is offset in full by capital loss deduction and your "taxable income" line is negative. The $1K that was not allowed - gets carried forward to the next year using the [Capital Loss Carryover Worksheet in the instructions to Schedule D](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040sd.pdf).

You calculate your NOL using [form 1045 schedule A](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Form-1045,-Application-for-Tentative-Refund). You can use the form 1045 to apply the NOL to prior 2 years, or you can elect to apply it *only* to future years (up to 20 years).

> In what cases, capital loss can be NOL?

Never.

Comment: Thanks!  (1) Because of low income, my tax  has been zero in 2010, 2011, 2012 and 2013 (though I paid tax before 2010).  Suppose I have NOL in 2013, does carryback of NOL (up to 2 years) not help me anything? By "you can elect to apply it only to future years (up to 20 years)", do you mean I can apply NOL to future 20 years if I have NOL? Is it still worth to find out if I have NOL in 2013?

Comment: (2) My line 41 of 1040 Form has been negative in 2010, 2011, 2012 and 2013, i.e. Itemized deductions is bigger than adjusted gross income. I may or may not have NOI (I need to follow form 1045 schedule A to find it out as you said). Is it also worth to find out if I have NOL in 2010, 2011, and 2012?

Comment: (1) (I) doesn't (II) yes, (III) yes.

Comment: (2) yes, it is. You can still amend 2011 and 2012. 2010 is lost.

Comment: Thanks! I am filing federal tax on www.freefilefillableforms.com, but I can't find form 1045 there. Can I mail 1045  separately to IRS, while still continue with and submit my 1045 and other forms on www.freefilefillableforms.com?

Comment: You can file it separately. Do read the instructions carefully, IIRC you must file it within a year of your original 1040 which may pose problems for 2011 and 2012.

Comment: Thanks! In form 1045 schedule A, I read the instruction, but not very sure: (1) in line 2 Nonbusiness Capital Losses, can I write the capital loss $12k from selling my mutual funds (which I reported in form 8949) or just the cap $3000? (2)in Line 6—Nonbusiness Deductions, can I write the standard deduction $6,100 (which I used in line 40 of form 1040)?

Comment: @Tim this is answered in the instructions very clearly.

Comment: Do "business" or "nonbusiness" mean that if they are related to my  trade or business (such as I was a graduate student last year with some income from being a TA)? (1) I saw Capital losses in excess of capital gains are not allowed for figuring NOL. But my capital loss of mutual fund is not related to my  trade or business (as a TA in graduate school), so why if it is not allowed for figuring NOL? (2) I saw the standard deduction is deduction not related to my trade or business, so I think I can write in in line 6 (http://www.irs.gov/publications/p536/ar02.html#en_US_2013_publink1000177329)

Comment: @Tim business means related to your Schedule C or Schedule E.

Comment: @Tim "why" is a meaningless question. Because the Congress said so. You don't like it - call your representative.

Comment: Thanks! If  my capital loss of selling mutual funds is not nonbusiness capital loss, then which is it related to: schecule C or E of 1040 form?

Comment: @Tim what schedule did you report it on?

Comment: Schedule D of form 1040, for reporting capital loss from selling my mutual funds

Comment: @Tim here you are, not so hard is it? So if business related is anything related to Schedules C and E - does your capital loss fit the bill?

Comment: thanks, but I am confused. my loss from selling fund is not related to schedule C or E of 1040 form, so my loss should be nonbusiness related? So I can write my loss in line 2 "nonbusiness capital losses" in schedule A of 1045 form ?

Comment: @Tim what is confusing you? Why the answer to your question should be anything but "yes" in your opinion? I think you can continue on your own from here.

Comment: thanks! in line 2 "Nonbusiness capital losses before limitation" in 1045 schedule A, should I enter my actual loss $15k or the loss $3k that I claim for 2013?